# Is there a way to use e.pageX/Y in a keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface

I'd like to move a cursor inside a canvas with the keyboard. I do it with the mouse, but now i want to pickup where i left the mouse and move it with the keyboard arrows.

If i want to use event.pageX from inside the keypress function, it's undefined, even thougg its defined when the mouse is moved. So, is there a way to pass the pageX value from the mouse function to the keyboard one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No; keyboard events don't have an inherent "location" like mouse events do. It sounds like what you're really trying to do is to have the cursor keys activate relative movements anyway, so just use your own stored location as the starting point.